# Maven and packages

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using Embeded maven inside eclipse , i dont know wether its a plugin , it was there by default. I setted up my dependencies and i currently have 2 packages inside my src folder. When I try to import one of the package inside one class of an another package I get this message: 
[image]

I am also using maven compiler plugin. Is there something that I need to add into the pom.xml file?

I dont know how to fix it!

Comment: Is this a maven project? i.e. is there a 'Maven' when you right click your project?

Comment: And please clarify what you are importing from where?

Comment: It is a maven project and absurd I have two packages  . I import package2 inside a class of package1

Comment: Then this has nothing to do with maven. Is the import correct? Do you import a class? Static import? What happens when you hit 'Organize imports'? You know that you didn't clear the name (`com.r...`) in the tooltip?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/3o4ji6 + When i hit organize nothing happens

Comment: Things to try: 1) Save the file 2) refresh the project (right click on project -> refresh) 3) clean the project (Projects -> Clean..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hit the clear button and you will be okay!